# I'm trying to mix netstandard2.0 and net48 in my project for a gradual transition to .NET Core. How do I fix this pipeline warning?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-devops, migration, azure-pipelines

Given that you have the following solution:

- Core.csproj -> net48
- MyProject.csproj -> netstandard2.0
- MyProject.Test.csproj -> netstandard2.0

I get the following warning:

```
##[warning]Src\MyProject.csproj(0,0): Warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform 3.6.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

I expected that you could mix .Net framework with .Net standard2.0 since that is the result of running these commands.

```sh
dotnet tool install -g upgrade-assistant --version 0.2.226201
upgrade-assistant --skip-backup --non-interactive MyProject.Test.csproj
```

What is the next step in this upgrade process? What are your experiences, did you use a gradual transition approach or a big bang approach? How do you estimate the time it takes to do a big bang approach?

Comment: What are the dependencies between the project? What are the start projects?

Comment: When you run the project on your local machine(visual studio), will it get the same issue?  You need to make sure that this project could build successfully(no warning)  on your local machine. Because this issue is from your project itself instead of Pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually got this to work using.NET 5.0 Core, you can mix and match versions, the warning is just to inform you of the risks. If you use C#9 specific syntax, this will break your code!

You can safely ignore this warning if you know what you are doing, just be sure to only use C#7 notation in the .Net 5 code base.

Another option is to compile it against multiple versions, again, this limits the expressions in your code to the lowest denominator.